# check a range with switch/case in fish shell

Tags: fish, case

Is something like this possible with fish? i.e.

```
switch $var
  case a-z
    do something
  case "*"
    do something else
end
```

`case "*"`works fine, but `case a-z`doesn't trigger. 
I also tried `case [ a-z ]` but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fish shell has not, for some reason, implemented character sets. Assuming you're using the latest version, use the [string command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string)

```
if string match --quiet --regex '[a-z]' $var >/dev/null
    echo $var contains a letter
else
    echo $var has no letters
end
```

I'm using regex matching due to the [minimal glob patterns](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand) in fish